# Image in collection view sets with animation issue

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uicollectionview, sdwebimage

I'm setting an image in UIImageView using SDWebimage in UICollectionView. The scenario is like that there is an expandable UILabel which expand and collapse by tapping on it. So on tapping it reloads the particular cell. This all works properly but the problem is that when user puts the app in background and then takes it in to foreground and again tap in UILabel then it reloads the cell and image now gets set in an animation like a glow affect in the screen.Below is the code which I'm using in collectionViewCell method.

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.imgBackground
                  duration:0.0f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                animations:^{
                    [self.imgBackground sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[dictData objectForKey:@"seasonImage"]]];
                    self.imgBackground.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
                    self.imgBackground.clipsToBounds = YES;
                } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                }];
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: Hi Sarim. These are the steps which I follow in my app and gets the animation issue:-  1.Get data from the server and load it in the collectionview.      2. Then tap on the label which is in the collectionview to move the collectionview contents position up and down.   3.Till 2nd point everything i just working fine, but if I move app to background and then take it in to foreground and after this tap on the label image again gets loaded in the collectionview but also the screen gets a glow affect like a camera flash.